# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset '' while iterating through an array

Tags: php, arrays, offset

I keep recieving an "Warning: Illegal string offset " error when trying to iterate over an array.

My result after using var_dump ---> 
array(19) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["handle"]=> string(4) "test" ["blockname"]=> string(0) "" ["project"]=> string(0) "" ["document_description"]=> string(4) "test" ["project_id"]=> string(0) "" ["revision"]=> string(0) "" ["scale"]=> string(0) "" ["document_num"]=> string(9) "test-1557" ["drawn_by"]=> string(0) "" ["approved_by"]=> string(0) "" ["checked_by"]=> string(0) "" ["issued_by"]=> string(0) "" ["drawn_date"]=> string(0) "" ["approved_date"]=> string(0) "" ["checked_date"]=> string(0) "" ["issued_date"]=> string(0) "" ["purpose"]=> string(0) "" ["notes"]=> string(0) "" }

So I assume it is actually an array?

And then I also check that its an array before running the loop. The error is repeated for the number of times I expect the loop to run, so it seems to be 'iterating'. Im just not getting the expected result.

My code

```
$titles = $titleBlockLib->search($_POST['document_description']);

      ?>
      <h1>LFFN Data</h1>
        <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="titleBlock.addEdit()"/>
        <form onsubmit="titleBlock.search()">
        <label for="search">Search:</label>
          <input id = "search" type="text">
          <input id = "submit" type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>

    <?php
      var_dump($titles);
        if (is_array($titles)) {
            echo "<table class='zebra'>
            <tr><td>Handle</td><td>Description</td><td>Document Number</td><tr>";
            foreach ($titles as $t) {
                printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s<td>%s</td><td class='right'>"
                  . "<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='titleBlock.del(%u)'>"
                  . "<input type='button' value='Edit' onclick='titleBlock.addEdit(%u)'>"
                  . "</td></tr>", 
                  $t['handle'], $t['document_description'], $t['document_num'],
                  $t['id'], $t['id']
                );
              }
              echo "</table>";
            } else {
              echo "<div>No data found.</div>";
            }
            break;
```

To be safe - The function that calls my SQL statement is as follows-->

```
function search($document_description){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `lffntitleblock` WHERE document_description LIKE '%".$document_description."%'";
    $this->stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $this->stmt->execute();
    $entry = $this->stmt->fetchAll();
    return count($entry)==0 ? false : $entry[0] ;

}
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug this problem?

Comment: -declaring $titles as an array
-casting $titles as an array
-hard coding my SQL LIKE statement

I've tried following through the Strack trace to see if i missed something or mistyped something. 

I have walked through the code, var_dumping each step to make sure it is what I expect. Which it has been.

I'll be honest and say I don't really know what else to try, Im not very familar with PHP and quite a new coder.  

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer..

My sql statement was returning..

```
count($entry)==0 ? false : $entry[0] ;
```

Which was a boolean.
After removing this statement and instead returning `$this->stmt->fetchAll();`
The problem was resolved.